GTM triggers will only trigger is a radio button is click and form submitted
I'm fairly new to GTM , I successfully set up a simple form submission triggers. but I need it only to capture submissions if a certain radio button is click , I the logic , get the value but I don't know how to implement this on GTM.
I have an event on analytics that can track the certain radio button when click - can I use this on GTM trigger?

Here is a Custom Java Script variable can help you can get the value of the input radio
function() {
  var clickedElement = {{Click Element}};
  
  if (clickedElement && clickedElement.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    return clickedElement.value;
  }
  return undefined;
}


Here is the example of how it work


For how to set the trigger
Here you observe what Google Tag Manager detect the click element is.
If you don't have the Click Element. You can enable it in your built-in Variable.

Here is a example of how to set the trigger

Click Element  => Matches CSS Selector => input[type='radio']

wo. Thanks Darrel this is really helpful , but how do i make this as condition on my trigger?

Hi @ChadwickComeros. Just update the trigger part!
